# Bootstrap Alignment (Cover Template)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a list of books shown on [image: this image] left without moving the `navigation bar/menu`. Below is my code. Can someone please advise what do I need to change in the following code to align the list left? I am using a `Bootstrap` template called "Cover." Thanks in advance!

```html
<body>
    <div class="cover-container d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
        <header class="masthead">
            <div class="inner">
                <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-end">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Reading list</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Meetings</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book summaries</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div>
            <h3>2021</h3><br>
            <h4>March</h4>
            <p><cite>The Laws of Human Nature</cite> by Robert Greene
                <br><cite>The Innovators: How a Group of Hackers, Geniuses and Geeks Created the Digital
                    Revolution</cite> by Walter Isaacson
            </p>
            <hr>
            <h4>February</h4>
            <p><cite>The Upstarts: How Uber, Airbnb, and the Killer Companies of the New Silicon Valley Are Changing the
                    World</cite> by Brad Stone
                <br><cite>The Raw Youth</cite> by Fyodor Dostoyevsky
            </p>
            <hr>
            <h4>January</h4>
            <p><cite>The Minto Pyramid Principle: Logic in Writing, Thinking, & Problem Solving</cite> by Barbara Minto
            </p>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you check your attached screenshot again? I can't see any list of books

Comment: You want to align it with the navigation?

Comment: Hi @Masood, No, I would like to align it with the far left side of the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Make your navbar div a separate `div` i.e close it before starting your list of books after that wrap all your books content in a `div` with class as "container-fluid"

Comment: Thank you, @RahulKhanna. Did you mean I should revise the code as follows? 
`<div class="container-fluid">
<h3>2021</h3><br>
<h4>March</h4>
<p><cite>The Laws of Human Nature</cite> by Robert Greene
...
</div>`

Comment: yes , you can also use your custom css to and checking it on the go using chrome developer tools @anna

Comment: Follow @RahulKhanna 's answer and if you saw any extra spacing in the left of your page add m-0 and p-0 classes following container-fluid class.